# Camel routing issue

Tags: apache-camel

I have created some routes. Following is the code which is having issues.
Following is the expected behavior:

1. Exchange at first gets processed at hourlyFeedParts queue and then passed to dailyProcessor.
2. In dailyProcessor a property currHour is being checked if it is 23 or not. If not, it just passes on.
3. If `currHour == 23`, code inside it shall be processed. This part again has following functionality,

   - If property `feedsleft` is not zero, all code inside the choice `currHour==23` is executed. This is fine.
   - if property `feedsLeft` is zero, code inside it processed. Code within looks for any further messages. If yes, they are send to `hourlyFeedParts`. **Here comes the issue:** If there is any message to be processed the code beyond `to("direct:hourlyFeedParts")` is not executed. Though, if nothing is returned, the code works fine.

I guess the issue could be code ends at `to`. So, what shall be the alternative?

```
from("direct:dailyProcessor")
  .choice()
    .when(simple("${property.currHour} == 23"))
    .choice()
      .when(simple("${property.feedsLeft} == 0"))
      .split(beanExpression(APNProcessor.class, "recheckFeeds"))
      .to("direct:hourlyFeedParts")
    .endChoice()
  .end()
  .split(beanExpression(new S3FileKeyProcessorFactory(), "setAPNS3Header"))
  .parallelProcessing()
  .id("APN Daily PreProcessor / S3 key  generator ")
  .log("Uploading file ${file:name}")
  .to("{{apn.destination}}")
  .id("APN Daily S3 > uploader")
.log("Uploaded file ${file:name} to S3")
.endChoice()
.end()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the issue is the nested choice().

try to extract the inner choice to a seperate route e.g.:

```
from("direct:dailyProcessor")
  .choice()
    .when(simple("${property.currHour} == 23"))
       .to("direct:inner")
  .split(beanExpression(new S3FileKeyProcessorFactory(), "setAPNS3Header"))
  .parallelProcessing()
  .id("APN Daily PreProcessor / S3 key  generator ")
  .log("Uploading file ${file:name}")
  .to("{{apn.destination}}")
  .id("APN Daily S3 > uploader")
.log("Uploaded file ${file:name} to S3");

from("direct:inner")
   .choice()
      .when(simple("${property.feedsLeft} == 0"))
      .split(beanExpression(APNProcessor.class, "recheckFeeds"))
      .to("direct:hourlyFeedParts");
```

I haven't tested it, but I guess you get the point.

Comment: This method didn't help